# How to register Consul service with service-name from database?

Tags: java, spring, registration, consul

**The main problem is** how to register a service with a name not from application.properties (application.yml)
I have an application that runs multiple times *(about 10-20 instances)* and takes configuration values from the database to run. If you take the service-name value from application.properties, then you will have to write your own configuration file for each individual instance. The database has a table that is read and stored in a specific class at startup (I can identify my service based on their environment variables (IP, MAC, etc).
*Can I take service name value from database and set it to service-name in Consul?*

**The class that registers the service**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnConsulEnabled
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type= "org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulLifecycle")
@AutoConfigureAfter(ConsulAutoServiceRegistrationAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ConsulLifecycle implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ConsulAutoServiceRegistration registration;

    public ConsulLifecycle(ConsulAutoServiceRegistration registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        if (registration != null ) {
            registration.start();
        }
    }
}
```

**A class that stores values from the database**

```
@Component
public class DatabaseValues {

   private String serviceName;

   //Getters, setters and inner logic
}
```

I can't figure out how to specifically create an object of type *ConsulAutoServiceRegistration* in order to register with the service name I need that i get from database before ConsulLifecycle is created in JVM.
If there is any other way to do the same functionality without this class, I will gladly try it!